# Save button background and drawables using SharedPreferences for a for loop

Tags: kotlin, sharedpreferences, drawable

A have a array of buttons which can have a different drawable and background depending if the button has been pressed. My question is: how can I save the drawable and background of each button in a for loop with SharedPreferences. I want to save this data because it gets reset after changing my screen orientation

Comment: Can you add some code? What have you tried so far and why is it not working?

Comment: If you want to keep only view state for buttons, you may use `ViewModel` which is not destroyed when the device orientation changes. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel